# Auto-Detect available database connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Normally when we connect to a database, we will select the database driver
type, server name, uid, password and database name. (like ms
sql server ). Is it possible my c# windows form app
auto detect available database connections?

Maybe the ms sql server database is store on the same PC where I
am running the app.

It is like the app can know there is a ms sql server
database and try to connect to the database.

I will aprreciate if you can please provide some example code

Thanks

Comment: if an app doesn't find the connection string, it throws an exception. And thrugh that exception you can get the message

Answer (score 2):

The `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` API may be what you are looking for, however I rarely see it used - in part because not everyone wants their servers discoverable, so they turn this feature off. Additionally, even if you can find the servers, it certainly won't tell you the credentials - you need to know those yourself (or use trusted auth).

But in almost all cases (unless you're writing a database utility like SSMS): your user should already know which source they need to connect to (even if that is just a magic opaque string that the admins give them).

For more info, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx) which has a full example.